# Can one setup automatkc commit (using Subclipse) on save?

Tags: python, eclipse, pydev, subclipse

I use eclipse plus pydev for python programming.  I have a local SVN repository and access it with Subclipse.  I would like to automatically trigger a commit when I save a file or close eclipse, but don't know how.  Can anyone give me a pointer?  Thanks.

Comment: I don't think there's a plugin that does that out of the box, so, if you really want that I guess you'd have to create your own plugin... as a note, Eclipse does have a local history for files, so, maybe that can suffice to you already (I know it did save me a few times).

Comment: Thanks for the quick response.  I was afraid that was the case.  And the local history has saved me several times too.  (I'm not nearly a good enough programmer to write my own.